# Formatting text with tabs or spaces in console.log - javascript/typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, formatting, console.log

How can below console.log output be formatted? Name column can be of different length so columns are not aligned correctly.
Example:-

[image]

Answer (score 3):

use `\t` for real tab in the output.

```js
console.log('name1\t14')
console.log('name2nam2\t12')
console.log('name3Nam3Nam\t13')
console.log('name1\t123421')
console.log('name1\t912421')
```

but probably what you want are `console.table` [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/table)

Answer (score 1):

Try using console.table() to format the data

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have access to `console.table()` (which is unavailable in some contexts, like Google App Scripts logging), you can use `string.padEnd()` to make all your strings the same length. It takes two arguments: the desired length, and the character to pad the string with. This will give you table-like formatting.

Example where we want the first column to be 28 characters wide:

```
  var keys = someObject.getKeys();
  var log = "";
  keys.forEach(key => {
    log += `${key.padEnd(28, ' ')}: \t${props.getProperty(key)}\n`;
  });
  console.log(log);
```

Output something like this:

```
previousRevisedWordCount    :   47690.0
previousPercent             :   0.4531134139945382
previousUnrevisedFileCount  :   59.0
previousUnrevisedWordCount  :   62924.0
previousDay                 :   Fri Feb 16 18:18:38 GMT-06:00 2024
previousRevisedFileCount    :   36.0
```

If you're iterating through a bunch of strings and you don't know the length, you could find the longest one first, then call `string.padEnd(n + 1, " ")`, where `n` is the length of the longest string.